# Iterator in Tensorflow returns same output after initialization

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a beginner.
I am using STL-10 dataset to train a CNN.

I am trying to obtain a randomly shuffled batch of 10 images from the train dataset.

```
img_tensor = get_images_tensor()
label_tensor = get_labels_tensor()
print img_tensor.get_shape()

def create_ds_from_tensor():
    #Creating Dataset from images and labels
    stl_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({"images":img_tensor,"labels":label_tensor})
    return stl_ds


def create_next_batch_iterator(dataset,seedin = 6,batch_size = 10):
    #Setting batch size
    batch_size = batch_size
    #Shuffling the dataset
    shuffled_ds = dataset.shuffle(100,seed = seedin,reshuffle_each_iteration = True)
    #Getting batch_size number of images
    batch = shuffled_ds.apply(tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder(batch_size))

    #Creating a iterator for the dataset
    #iterator = batch.make_one_shot_iterator()
    iterator = batch.make_initializable_iterator()
    #Getting the next batch
    #next_batch = iterator.get_next()
    return iterator

def get_next_batch(iterator):
    return iterator.get_next()

#Create session
sess = tf.Session()
dataset = create_ds_from_tensor()
iterator = create_next_batch_iterator(dataset)
next_batch = get_next_batch(iterator)['labels']
sess.run(iterator.initializer)
count = 0
init_count = 1
while True:
    try:
        print(sess.run(next_batch))
        count+=1
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print 'End of Dataset'
        #break
        sess.run(iterator.initializer)
        init_count+=1
        print init_count,' initialization'
        if init_count==10:
            break
```

Now, the problem is that when I see the outputs I am getting, I observe that the output are same after each re-initialization.

After 1st End of dataset and 1st re-initalization initialization

```
End of Dataset
2 initialization
[6 1 7 6 9 3 8 4 6 2]
```

After 2nd End of dataset and 2nd re-initalization initialization

```
End of Dataset
3 initialization
[6 1 7 6 9 3 8 4 6 2]
```

But how change should I make to this code so that I get a different output even after re-initialization?

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me as if you're using the same seed in every initialization. This will obviously result in the same shuffling every time. In the current TF version it should be enough to not set any seed, i.e. a "new" re-shuffling should be the default behavior.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out after doing some study. Anyway, Thanks.